# how to read the mutiple files and then concatenate: I have function to check if file exist and read if exist, Facing issue while concatenation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

There are 5 files in 5 different folder, I have a function written to check if file exist and to read the file and store in the dataframe. I have concatenate function say pd.concat(file1,file2,file3,file,4,file5).
Issue : 
Not everytime we get all 5 files, few time I get 4 files only, function will read the file but issue is at concatenation.
ex: File 2 does not exist , it give me error File 2 is not defined.

Code :

```
for x in f:
    if x.startswith("File_A1"):
        mypath = os.path.join(root,'A1','ABB','BGH',x)
        A1 = pd.read_csv(mypath, delimiter="|",header = 1)
        A1['GROUP']= 'A1'
        A1.loc[A1['coms'] == "ASIA"]
        A1.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)


    elif x.startswith("File_A2"):
        mypath = os.path.join(root,'A2','ABB','BGH',x)
        A2 = pd.read_csv(mypath,delimiter="|",header = 1)
        A2['GROUP']= 'A2'
        A2.loc[A2['coms'] == "ASIA"]
        A2.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)

    elif x.startswith("File_A3"):
        mypath = os.path.join(root,'A3','ABB','BGH',x)
        A3 = pd.read_csv(mypath,delimiter="|",header = 1)
        A3['GROUP']= 'A3'
        A3.loc[A3['coms'] == "ASIA"]
        A3.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)



df = pd.concat([A1,A2,A3])
```

Comment: You need to show some relevant part of your code to completely understand your problem. For starters, make sure that each file exists and read in a dataframe and each dataframe has the same structure(columns)

Answer (score 0):

I think best is create list of DataFrames by `append`:

EDIT: You can loop by list of starts of filenames and `A1`, `A2` create dynamically by `start.split('_')[1]`:

```
dfs = []
for x in f:
    starts = ["File_A1", "File_A2", "File_A3"]
    for start in starts:
        if x.startswith(start):
            mypath = os.path.join(root,start.split('_')[1],'ABB','BGH',x)
            df = pd.read_csv(mypath, delimiter="|",header = 1)
            df['GROUP']= start.split('_')[1]
            df.loc[df['coms'] == "ASIA"]
            df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
            dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```